# Может ли модератор принять ответ на вопрос за автора?

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, ответы, принятые-ответы, инструменты-модератора

Я немного печалюсь, когда юзеры-новички, получив ответ на вопрос, говорят спасибо и этим ограничиваются. А некоторые даже этого не делают. Почему модераторы не отмечают правильные ответы? Ведь мы здесь не смысл жизни обсуждаем - для большинства вопросов можно четко определить, правилен ответ или нет. Есть, конечно, неоднозначные ситуации - например, когда есть два различных правильных ответа, и непонятно, какой выбрать, или когда ответ неправильный, но помог автору вопроса решить проблему, и т.д. Но есть и совершенно однозначные ситуации.

Comment: похожий вопрос: [Moderators accepting answers on user's behalf after a certain time period](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18312/137096)

Comment: В этом вопросе был принят неправильный ответ. Модератор не мог принять правильный, но хотя бы смог удалить принятый неправильный. Вот такая ирония.

Answer (score 17):

> Почему модераторы не отмечают правильные ответы?

Движок не позволяет и это [плохая идея в любом случае](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262915/4279) (вопрос, на который [@Nofate♦ сослался](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/167/%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0#comment326_168)):

- **принятый** ответ по определению только автор вопроса может отметить—это ответ, который помог автору (по мнению автора же)—это не означает что ответ "правильный"
- модератор не может быть экспертом по всем темам, обсуждаемым на сайте. И даже мнение экспертов может быть разным:

  - поэтому больше одного ответа можно добавить к вопросу, вместо редактирования одного ответа (большинство вопросов на здоровом SE-сайте, должно иметь более одного ответа)
  - чтобы выразить своё мнение о правильности/полезности ответа, можно проголосовать за/против

Большинство задач модератора не требуют (и это даже вредит) знания конкретной предметной области. Только некоторые задачи (такие как закрытие дубликатов) одновременно требуют эксперта и модераторских полномочий.

Comment: Для закрытия дубликатов экспертам дается золотой мьйолльнир, позволяющий закрывать вопрос как дубликат сразу и единолично. Так что даже для этого не нужны модераторские полномочия.

Comment: Зачем тогда говорят, что собирают базу вопросов и ответов, полезных для всех разработчиков?

Comment: @NickVolynkin: я не имел в виду, что только модераторы могут дубликаты закрывать. Я хотел сказать, что из многих обязанностей модератора, только некоторые (типа закрытия дубликатов) требуют экспертных знаний.

Comment: @Alex78191: какое утверждение в моём ответе противоречит *"собирают базу вопросов и ответов, полезных для всех разработчиков"* по вашему?

Comment: @jfs То, что только автор может отметить ответ решением. Если бы было полезно для всех, то все могли бы выбирать решение.

Comment: @Alex78191 для этого голосование на ответах существует. Автор отмечает ответ, который помог лично ему — принятие ответа ничего больше и не означает — это написано на вводной страничке https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @jfs это значит, что SO сделан не полностью на благо сообщества, потому что зачем сообществу принятые неправильные ответы?

Comment: @Alex78191 если согласно *вашему мнению* вы нашли неправильный ответ, то поставьте минус, оставьте комментарий что по вашему неправильно в ответе и/или опубликуйте свой "правильный" ответ. SO не высечен из камня: если вы считаете что что-то можно изменить, что улучшит сайт, то предлагайте.

Comment: Всё ещё непонятно, почему не отмечают. Допустим, автор явно написал в комментарии к ответу вида «Это помогло, спасибо», но галочку не поставил и убежал. Иногда на явную просьбу поставить галочку отвечают «Не вижу / Не могу» и тоже убегают. Здесь модератору не требуется знать предметную область и как-то самостоятеьно выбирать правильный ответ — автор его уже выбрал, только не галочкой, а комментарием. Почему же модератору нельзя поставить галочку в данном случае?