# Что делать: ответ не принят, пользователя нет?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, принятые-ответы

Меня не устраивает ответ: "ничего".

На заданный вопрос есть ответ, и даже одобрительный комментарий задавшего его пользователя сайтом. Смею предположить, что новичок просто не усвоил регламент сайта и оставил ответ не принятым. По факту, он даже больше не заходил на сайт, а вопрос остался на сайте,  и продолжает нести обучающую роль.

На ХэшКоде был стандартный комментарий: "если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, примите его, поставив галочку слева" - получив его, я немного пристыдился, что не усвоил правила - и принял ответ, тем самым сняв его из выборки.

Может существует какая нибудь инструкция, для заморозки таких вопросов, или признание ответа модератором?

UPD:    [один из таких вопросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/448936/)

Comment: Добавил этот вопрос в [Часто задаваемые вопросы о StackOverflow](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/983)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, никто не читает FAQ :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Что означает галочка на ответе:

- Автор вопроса решил использовать этот ответ для решения своей задачи.

Что не означает галочка на ответе:

- Это вообще хоть насколько-то решение,
- Это правильное решение,
- Это лучшее из предложенных решений,
- Это надежное и безопасное решение.

В некоторых редких случаях автор вопроса вообще пишет ответ «кароч проблема решилась» и принимает его, игнорируя нормальные решения. Конечно, так делать нельзя — но так бывает. Поэтому галочка имеет довольно малое значение.

[Комментарий к недавней статье на Хабре про StackOverflow](http://habrahabr.ru/company/Voximplant/blog/266305/#comment_8562371):

> А я с некоторых пор перестал смотреть на зеленые галочки — смотрю только топовые ответы. Зеленые галочки ставит только один человек, задавший вопрос, а топовость ответов выбирает все сообщество.

Поэтому, что нужно делать:

- просто проголосовать за ответ, если он вам помог или вы одобряете выбранный путь решения;
- написать автору вопроса комментарий, точно такой же как на ХэшКоде. Не стесняйтесь писать его даже если это ваш ответ остался непринятым. Иногда авторы заходят и принимают ответы;

  - если ответов несколько, не стоит писать «примите мой ответ». Можно сформулировать, например, так:

    > Если какой-нибудь из предложенных ответов вас устроил, пожалуйста, примите его (галочка слева от текста). Если нет — задавайте уточняющие вопросы в комментариях.
- [модератор принимать ответ не будет, потому что не имеет такой возможности](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/186/181472).

На десерт:
[image]

Comment: По второй ссылке как раз пример, почему не всегда стоит верить зеленым галочкам.

Comment: @Nofate: да, точно )) Barmaley там говорит, что это возможно, хотя в новом движке — нет.

Comment: Ответ был бы неполным без картинки: http://i.imgur.com/dOLkgVR.png

Comment: @PashaPash: каждая буква этой картинки меня смешит. )

Comment: @Nofate: перенаправил ссылку на правильный ответ.

Comment: _модератор принимать ответ не будет_ - а сможем ли мы тогда достичь отметки 85% отвеченных вопросов? Или закрытием/удалением вопросов будет решаться проблема?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ответ без галочки но с голосами делает вопрос отвеченным. Подробнее: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/807/181472 , http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1339/181472

Comment: Понял. Спасибо.

Comment: Как как быть с тем, если автор вопроса больше не посещает сайт более полугода? Вопрос будет всегда неотвеченый?

Comment: @nick_n_a с точки зрения системы, если есть хоть один ответ с +1 и выше — [вопрос отвеченный](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/807/181472). А вообще да, так бывает, что автор вопроса пропадает. Вот мой любимый пример, там автор даже не зарегистрировался. [Как работает текст «Залго»?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/612002/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82-%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be)

Answer (score 0):

Нужно понимать весьма ограниченные рамки, в которых имеет смысл задавать вопросы на мете.

Этот сайт - для разрешения *технических* вопросов, таких как баги верстки, исправление тегов и пр.

На вопросы, связанные с улучшением качества контента ответ всегда будет один - "Тут так заведено. Не устраивает? Постарайтесь расслабиться и получить удовольстие."