# Автор вопроса отметил ответ как ... ответ с зелёной галочкой

Tags: предложение, локализация, принятые-ответы

Зелёная галочка на ответе является довольно-таки неоднозначным объектом. Обычно пользователи воспринимают её как знак того, что отмеченный ответ — верный или лучше прочих.

Вот что написано во всплывающей подсказке ([Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40261975?qt=%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9)).

> Автор вопроса отметил ответ как лучший $when$

Вот вопросы, которые об этом задаются:

- [Что делать: ответ не принят, пользователя нет?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1299/181472)
- [Может ли модератор принять ответ на вопрос за автора?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/167/181472) (здесь принятый ответ неверен).

Но на самом деле [галочка означает только то](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1301/181472), что автор использовал предложенное решение. Принятый ответ даже [может быть в корне неверным или вредоносным](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/961/181472).

**Предлагаю заменить описание на соответствующее действительности.**

Comment: Учитывая такую постановку вопроса, можно сделать вывод, что галка не нужна вовсе. Количество плюсов, кстати говоря, тоже не говорит о том, что ответ правильный или исчерпывающий. Он может быть просто дан раньше других или "... и еще по куче субъективных причин" (с) avp.

Comment: @YuraIvanov: можете проголосовать за ответ avp.

Comment: okay...........

Comment: @YuraIvanov: оценить ответ, как правило, проще чем его найти (это верно для многих вещей, например, люди понимают больше слов чем регулярно сами используют или ещё пример: обычные люди распознают больше лиц, чем могут описать, по памяти, NP!=P задача) -- галка говорит ***в большинстве случаев***: ответ помог автору вопроса решить задачу, изложенную в вопросе. Достаточно часто это не самый популярный среди голосующих ответ. Оба критерия (полезность для автора и популярность) являются по своему полезными (всё лучше чем выкапывать что-то похожее на решение из форумов/списков рассылок на 10 cтр.)

Comment: @jfs С точки зрения базы знаний эти критерии не значат ничего, и самое главное могут быть вредными. И на en.SO у меня в правило вошло читать все ответы и комментарии, потому что часто бывает, что принятый или заплюсованный ответ может быть либо устаревшим, либо костыльным. Галка - рудимент.

Comment: @YuraIvanov: Если Ваш тезис, что критерии ***всегда*** бесполезны (*"Галка - рудимент"*), то он это не верно. Если Ваш тезис, что **иногда** принятые/популярные ответы могут быть не самыми полезными, то это верно. Оба тезиса легко проверить количественно: возьмите сотню случайных вопросов и посмотрите какие ответы приняты/больше голосов и насколько они полезны по сравнению с другими ответами (по Вашему мнению). Повторюсь, если это не ясно из первого комментария: мой тезис ***в большинстве случаев*** принятые/популярные ответы являются полезными по сравнению с другими ответами.

Comment: @jfs без экспертной оценки **каждого** принятого ответа на правильность тезис о принятых=правильных ответах не работает. Речи про большинство, когда дело касается правил сообщества,  как аргумент не годятся. Примером тому данный топик и топики по ссылкам. Если есть хотя бы одна галка для устаревшего/неверного/костыльного ответа, тогда галка уже не значит ничего. Когда человек приходит из поиска ему никто не расскажет входит данный вопрос в ваше большинство или нет и проверять ответы придётся в любом случае.

Comment: @YuraIvanov: "лучший" -- это просто неверный перевод. Посмотрите хотя бы, что тур говорит о принятых ответах (подсказка именно это должна показывать). Человек не обязан знать ничего о сайте, чтобы пользу получить. Но утверждение, что все ответы необходимо всегда читать -- абсурдно: почему весь интернет не перечитать? Нужно применять здравый смысл и остановится на каком-то этапе — не каждый вопрос в диссертацию надо превращать.

Comment: @jfs Указанное в туре и то, о чем здесь голосуют - нечевидно для стороннего посетителя. С таким же успехом галка может означать, что у автора ответа был день рождения и ему галочку поставили. Подсказки (я их, например не читаю, не весь же интернет перечитывать), тур (для посетителей из поиска неизвестная страница) - это все шашечки. Галка должна быть self describing... // Больше половины ваших ответов не имеют галки, прям щас пойдете удалять? Все равно их читать по вашему бессмысленно, не говоря уж о том, что бывают вопросы без принятых ответов, сразу их пропускать... ;)

Comment: @YuraIvanov: Я думал, что Вы шутите по поводу принятых ответов. Если Вы серьёзно думаете что понятия принятых ответов/голосование бесполезно, то сходите на форумы/почитайте списки рассылок, которые я упомянул в первом комментарии, где этого нет и посмотрите сколько времени требуется, чтобы полезный ответ найти по сравнению с SO в большинстве случаев. SO это инструмент -- если вы не читаете подсказки и не прошли тур, то можете ожидать, что не получите полной пользы от сайта. Если человек зашёл один раз, то это и не важно -- наличие галки не препятствует чтению ответов.

Answer (score 6):

> Автор вопроса отметил данный ответ как решающий его задачу $when$.

Comment: мнение: формулировка приводит к выводу что задача закрыта полностью с верным решением,  без ущерба для всех; что опять-таки есть вероятность  "не соответствия действительности".

Comment: @Shilgen: верно. «Использовал для решения» это не то же что «решил задачу».

Comment: @Shilgen С другой стороны, галка нужна именно для того, чтобы сказать сообществу - «этот ответ помог мне решить проблему».

Answer (score 5):

> Автор вопроса использовал данный ответ для решения своей задачи $when$.

Comment: Голосую за.  Мнение: формулировка приводит к выводу что "использование данного ответа" привело к решению задачи, не уточняя о ущербе и правильности ( возможно автор нашёл зацепку в этом вопросе, с помощью которой и был решен вопрос)

Answer (score 5):

Вот ещё вариант в духе обсуждения:

> Автор вопроса считает этот ответ лучшим, принят $when$

Comment: Коротко и ясно.

Answer (score 3):

Текст подсказки:

> ответ помог решить задачу по мнению автора вопроса, принят: $when$.

Comment: Хорошо, плюсанул. Но я бы немного поменял порядок слов: "по мнению автора..."

Comment: Я понимаю, что так *должно быть* (если следовать правилам, туру по сайту и т.п.), но можно ли в самом деле утверждать, что этот ответ *помог решить задачу* (да еще и приписывать данное утверждение *автору вопроса*)?

Comment: @avp: галку автор вопроса нажимает. А люди, которые на всё попало нажимают, не глядя ни на подсказки ни на сообщения в UI (подталкивающие к действиям) и т.д., не являются большинством и им ничто не поможет.

Comment: А мне кажется, что как раз *большинство* правила, хэлпы, туры и т.п. читает только "когда ничего не получается".

Comment: @avp: верно (например, можно посмотреть что [знак "информированный" (просмотрел тур)](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed) только около 10% [пользователей имеют](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41168/stack-overflow-in-russian)), но разве я это сказал? Например, когда подсказка видна? Если человек мышку  к галке подвёл (потому что система напомнила, что хорошо бы вопрос принять со ссылкой на то, что это значит или просто от любопытства), чтобы нажать на галку, то подсказка сама появится (не нужно ничего про правила, помощь, обзорную страницу знать, чтобы её увидеть).

Comment: Ну, да. Там (при наведении мыши) написано -- "если решил проблему *или помог больше других* ..." -- одним словом -- **лучший** из всех ответов, но не обязательно именно он решил проблему.

Comment: @avp "лучший" слишком расплывчато — критерии могут быть разными. [В обзорной странице достаточно ясно сказано](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1303/%d0%90%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bb-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%91%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9/1308#comment4880_1308)

Answer (score 2):

Оставить как есть, поскольку на самом деле зеленая галка ни о чем не говорит.

В конце-концов автор вопроса мог нажать на нее случайно, с целью отметить лично симпатичного ему автора ответов, на первый же пришедший ответ ... и еще по куче субъективных причин.

Поэтому простая констатация факта

```
Автор вопроса отметил ответ как лучший
```

ничем не хуже остальных вариантов.

Comment: Почему не говорит. Говорит! И очень много. Поставте себя на место новичка который нашел свой вопрос да еще с ответами (на сколько я понимаю это вообще цель всей свистопляски которой мы тут с вами занимаемся), какой он ответ по вашему посчитает наиболее правильным? "О! Тут стоит зеленая галка, наверно это ничего не значит, возьму как я ответ с самого снизу", - так чтоли?

Comment: @Cerbo, ну уж то, что автор использовал ответ, отмеченный галкой (как предлагается в остальных ответах) это тоже лишь одно из предположений. Мы тут можем только спорить о том, какое из них наиболее вероятно. Мой же вариант это просто краткая перефразировка (суть) того текста, который сейчас выводится при наведении курсора на галку. / (А цель этой свистопляски у каждого своя.)

Comment: [тур по сайту](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) явно говорит: *"Принятие ответа не означает, что этот ответ лучший; это значит, что изложенное в нем решение сработало для автора вопроса."*