# Расширение возможностей/обязанностей модераторов - отмечать решением самоответы старше года

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, модерация

Одним из правил является то, что

> Только участник имеет право отмечать ответ на свой вопрос решением

Однако на сайте есть [вопросы с самоответами, которые автор не отметил решением](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/595398/191745) (забыл, ушел с сайта и т.п.).

И такие вопросы периодически всплывают, отвлекая внимание, потому как если есть ответы по твоей тематике и нет принятого ответа, разумно зайти в вопрос и посмотреть в чем причина(сложность, плохие ответы и т.п.).

Было бы неплохо расширить возможности модератора, а именно разрешить им  отмечать самоответ как решение при соблюдении следующих условий:

1. Нет принятых ответов (само собой разумеющееся).
2. Самоответу больше года.
3. Под самоответом уже есть комментарий с просьбой отметить самоответ как решение и данному комментарию больше 1 месяца. Если комментария нет, его нужно сперва добавить и подождать 1 месяц.
4. Участник не появляется на сайте больше 1 месяца.

Этим мы немного <strike>усложним жизнь модераторам</strike> улучшим ru.so

В случае принятия предложения необходимо:

1. Указать в *справке* данные правило/условия
2. Под отмеченным как решение самоответом автоматически публиковать комментарий(опционно) с текстом "*самоответ отмечен решением модератором Name( ссылка на модератора) ввиду достижения условий(ссылка на условия для отметки решением самоответа)*"

В идеале было бы неплохо:

1. Сделать модераторам отдельную очередь по таким вопросам
2. Программно запретить ставить отметку решения модераторам до достижения данных условий (не обязательно, <strike>неадекватных модераторов на ru.so пока не замечено</strike> модераторы действуют по правилам общества, их действия обсуждаемы и негативные действия наказуемы).

---

1. 1 месяц выбран потому, что участник может быть в отпуске или занят и поэтому не заходит на сайт и не отмечает свой ответ решением. Одного месяца обычно хватает на отдых или для решения срочных дел. Можно установить иной срок для условия отметки самоответ решением.
2. Да, вопрос <strike>по ссылке</strike> в примере пока не подпадает под условия, но на сайте и без него есть вопросы подпадающие под эти условия.
3. Вероятно данное предложение будет актуально для всех разделов so.

---

***Вопрос только по самоответам***, т.е. автор написал решение своего вопроса, но не поставил отметку решения.

Comment: статус-отклонено.

Comment: чего вы хотите добиться при помощи этого? больше *зеленых галочек*?

Comment: @Grundy не дубликат, речь о самоответах автора, когда он явно пишет, *я решил так* и уходит не ставя отметку решения.

Comment: @Bald чтобы данные вопросы не всплывали, а если и всплывали, то было видно, что они имеют решение. и да зеленых галочек и, соответственно, ответов с принятыми ответами будет больше.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я прочитал, что *[движок не позволяет](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/186/191745)*, но сайт наверняка обновляется периодически и если то или иное предложение разумно, то почему бы не поставить его в очередь задач на следующий update.

Comment: Даже если и принимать подобную функциональность, то логичнее вешать такую обязанность на духа, алгоритм вполне чёткий.

Comment: @AK да, но дух может ошибаться, автор может написать что угодно в ответе и он может не быть решением, т.е. в данном случае нужно предусмотреть возможность смены отметки решения если дух ошибся, но это еще больше может усложнить функционал.

Comment: @Alex ну будет 90% ответов с зелеными галочками, и что. сама по себе галочка ничего не значит и ни о чем не говорит

Comment: @Bald 1- дух не поднимет такой вопрос. 2 - если вопрос поднимется из-за правки или нового ответа, из очереди будет видно, что вопрос имеет решение, сейчас же пустой квадрат(нет решения).

Comment: А такие вопросы по идее должны в большинстве своём  подпадать под [условия автоудаления](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2293/213987), ну либо если вам вопрос не нравится -- то можно подсобить закрытию ;)

Comment: @AK под условия не попадет(есть ответ с >=0), а закрывать не совсем правильно если есть опубликованное решение.

Comment: @Alex В этом случае - да, но посмотрите: ведь в этом конкретном случае последний заход на сайт топикстартера -- три месяца назад. Может не всё так печально?

Comment: @AK именно поэтому одно из условий - комментарий старше 1 месяца с просьбой отметить самоответ как решение. Вопрос родился потому что периодически такие вопросы всплывают и с ними ничего нормального не сделаешь(кроме +-).

Comment: Вы не обозначили цель и пользу. Чем сайту будет лучше от этого?

Comment: @NickVolynkin а разве принятое решение на вопрос автора не несет пользу? 1 - польза сайту от принятых ответов, 2 - польза участнику - нет мусора из старых вопросов в очереди, 3 - польза участнику - в очереди меньше вопросов без ответа, соответственно больше времени для другого вопроса, который **нуждается** в ответе. Наверняка многие попадались на такие вопросы, когда заходишь в вопрос, а там есть непринятое решение от N года. Пусть хотя бы вопросы с **самоответами** отпадут.

Comment: @Alex не понял 1) в чем именно польза сайту 2) что за очередь со старыми вопросами и 3) что за очередь вопросов без ответа? Вы имеете в виду результаты поискового фильтра? Вы их используете, когда ищете вопросы, на которые можете дать ответ?

Comment: @NickVolynkin 1) статистика (мелочь но все же), 2,3) очередь на главной странице, т.е. вопросы на главной странице

Comment: @Alex 2-3) на главной странице нет вопросов, на которые ответ дан месяц назад. Их только поиском можно найти.

Comment: А почему модераторам, а не обладателям золотого знака по метке?

Comment: @Qwertiy модераторы это первые о ком думаешь) по "золотым" стоит подумать, но есть за и против этого

Comment: @NickVolynkin странно, видимо была правка. тогда 2,3 - это только то, что ответ если и будет поднят из-за каких-то действий, то будет видно, что у него есть решение.

Answer (score 6):

## Самоответ может быть плохим

Самоответ может быть ошибочным или недостаточно подробным для ответа. Нередко автор пишет *о решении*, но не приводит само решение:

> Проблема была в строке 123, я переписал и стало зашибись.

Бывает, что автор использовал плохое или деструктивное решение:

> Добавил `--force`, пуш прошёл без конфликтов, всем спасибо. Всегда используйте `push --force`!

## Качество ответа оценивают участники-эксперты, а не модераторы

Модераторы не являются экспертами во всех областях программирования. Поэтому мы не можем взять на себя ответственность выбирать правильные ответы.

При этом в каждой области есть достаточно компетентные участники.
Они проголосуют за хорошие самоответы и против плохих.
Этого достаточно, чтобы выделить хорошие самоответы.

## Галочка на собственном ответе почти ни на что не влияет

Вы так и не объяснили, в чём именно польза сайту от галочки.
Сам я тоже не знаю.

Статистика отвеченных вопросов нам почти не интересна с тех пор, как сайт вышел из беты.
Но даже если будет интересна, если к вопросу дан ответ без галочки, но заплюсованный, то вопрос считается отвеченным.
Опять же, галочка влияет только если у ответа рейтинг — ноль.

Для справки:

- [Может ли модератор принять ответ на вопрос за автора?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/167/181472)
- [Что делать: ответ не принят, пользователя нет?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1299/181472)

Comment: Вы немного не правы. Есть решение, а есть качество ответа. Так вот, что является решением на его вопрос определяет автор, а качество ответа определяет общество.

Comment: @Alex галочка добавляет убедительности ответу. Модератор не может взять на себя ответственность и выделить один из ответов галочкой. Если разбирается в теме — может поставить плюс или минус.

Comment: Галочка (кроме самоответов) закрепляет ответ на первом месте независимо от сортировки.

Comment: Вы действительно поверите ответу с галочкой с несколькими минусами  если есть иной ответ с рейтингом >=0 ? или все же постараетесь выяснить причины минусов и сравнить ответы ?

Comment: @Qwertiy тут речь как раз о самоответах. Для остальных ответов эффект действительно ещё сильнее.

Comment: @Alex не поверю. И зачем тогда ему галочка?

Comment: конечно есть вероятность  *на ru.so взял, он там как отмеченный ответ * )

Comment: @NickVolynkin а я проверяю, потому что со временем могут появится другие ответы в вопросе, гораздо лучшие(прогресс). по поводу эффекта - поэтому речь и идет только о самоответах.

Comment: галочка указывает на решение, выбранное автором вопроса (/tour), которое (если это не самоответ) поднимает ответ на самый верх и +15 автору ответа, не ограненных +200 дневным пределом (вроде комментария «спасибо» от автора). То есть принятый ответ не обязан быть лучшим, правильным итд.  Первоначально со-основатель SO был [против принятых самоответов](https://stackoverflow.blog/2008/12/01/why-cant-i-accept-my-own-answer/), но позже [поменял частично свою точку зрения](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/). Галка отражает мнение автора вопроса. Модератор не автор.

Comment: "Галочка почти ни на что не влияет" ... вот и я так думал, [пока не забанили](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302850/does-unaccepting-violate-site-rules).

Comment: @jfs обычно автор пишет "сделал так" или "решил так" и т.п., после чего забывает про вопрос и уходит с сайта, нередко навсегда или просто забывает сделать отметку. Хотя имеет место быть вероятность, когда автор пишет в поле ответа то, что ему помогло частично. Однако я думаю частичное решение можно определить, хотя бы посоветовавшись в чате участниками. Явный минус этого предложения в том, что это прибавит работы модераторам.

Comment: @Alex если принять предложение, то нарушается простое правило «зелёная галка выставляется только автором вопроса»—сайт и так сложный. А польза не ясна (порядок сортировки не меняется, спасибо от имени автора, самому автору говорить — это странно). Если считаете ответ полезным, ставьте плюс, или конкурс откройте, чтобы супер-плюс поставить.