# Дать возможность принимать ответы на вопросы другим пользователям

Tags: предложение, принятые-ответы

Иногда бывает, что заходит какой-то пользователь, задает вопрос.

На него пишут ответ, ответ получает море лайков, но сам пользователь "самоуничтожается"(т.е не проходит регистрацию до конца) после получения ответа не приняв его как верный.

Почему бы не сделать очередь принятия ответов на вопрос, где есть ответы, а сами ответы имеют хорошее кол-во лайков?

Во многих случаях по содержанию ответа очевидно, что он верный. Так почему бы его не принять?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/21043/260198

Comment: @Grundy не дубликат. Там скорее "поддержка", а тут именно желание изменить.

Comment: @älёxölüt, а результат тот же. Хотя вот этот дубликат лучше подходит :-) https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1299/186999

Comment: @Grundy Та же самая "поддержка" из разряда "как быть", а не "сделайте, чтобы было можно".

Comment: @PashaPash ну, не дубликат же!

Comment: @älёxölüt вопрос другой, ответ - тот же

Comment: @PashaPash это такое завуалированное обвинение в плагиате? :-D Какой ответ-то, можете дать ссылку? Чтобы понимать вообще общую часть.

Comment: @älёxölüt я не про ваш ответ, я в целом про применимость ответов в прилинкованных темах к вопросу :)

Answer (score 2):

Наверное, можно было бы так сделать для повышения статистики принятых ответов. Насколько я помню, так сделано на форумах MSDN, где ответы принимаются модераторами через некоторое время. Наказывают их там что ли за долго висящие вопросы без принятого ответа - я не знаю. Но, емнип, наблюдал ситуации, когда принятым становился ответ, совсем не подходящий ТС, а это вообще довольно печальная ситуация.

Возвращаясь к SO, что даёт принятие ответа, помимо красивой зелёной галочки? На SO есть такое понятие как "неотвеченный вопрос" (unanswered question). Это не просто вопрос без ответов, как может показаться в первую очередь, а вопрос, у которого нет **заплюсованных или принятых** ответов. Таким образом, если ТС слился, не отдав голос и не поставив галочку, а ответ действительно полезный, то с большой вероятностью кто-то его плюсанёт, и вопрос покинет ряды "неотвеченных". Статистика неотвеченных вопросов таким образом не пострадает.

На странице вопроса всегда можно выбрать сортировку по голосам и полезный ответ без наличия рядом принятого будет всегда наверху. Посетитель страницы, ищущий ответ, ничего не потеряет. Хотя допускаю, что зелёная галочка это дополнительный символ для привлечения внимания читателя.

Теперь по репутации. За принятие ответа ТС получает +2 репы. Должен ли он продолжать её получать, если кто-то за него поставит галочку? Автор принимаемого ответа получает +15 реп. И снова тот же вопрос, если кто-то, кто не задавал исходный вопрос, принимает ответ, имеет ли он (они, если это делается по мажоритарной схеме) право выдавать эти дополнительные 15 реп? За хороший ответ можно проголосовать, и его автор получит +10 реп без каких-то дополнительных очередей и изменения имеющегося функционала сайта. Имхо, это уже хорошее поощрение от участника, который просто попал на страницу вопроса и не писал ответов, а только читал.

Короче говоря, сделать было бы и можно, но надо во-первых продумать всю эту систему, а во-вторых оценить сложность её изменения. Первое стоит делать тому, кто предлагает такое изменение, а второе уже руководству SO. И скорее всего профита в этом будет немного. Дополнительно стоит учесть, что такой функционал является базовым и в случае применения должен затронуть **все сайты сети**, а стало быть предлагать надо, как минимум, на MSE. А так как такой [вопрос уже существует более 9 лет](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/21043/339911) и при этом никак не отмечен красными модераторскими метками, вряд ли стоит ожидать какое-то изменение в ближайшем времени без появления новых условий для реализации в самом предложении.

Comment: Вот запиненность принятого ответа - весьма существенная фича, которой хотелось бы как-то управлять если автор вопроса смылся. А репутацию можно и не давать.

Comment: @Qwertiy имеете в виду ситуации, когда ТС принял "не тот ответ"?

Comment: Обе - и принял не тот, и не принял никакой.